# Quantum beats and Quantum mechanical side of photosynthesis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy, biology

I have two questions. One concerning quantum beats alone, another - process of photosynthesis.

I am very well aware that there is strong evidence suggesting that mechanism that leads  light through, for example, chloroplast (though all of those cholophyll molecules) to reaction centre where the real photosynthesis begins, is quantum mechanical.

I am trying to understand in very simple terms at the moment how guys here [(link)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v446/n7137/full/nature05678.html) managed to do it by measuring quantum beats.

So they shot very short impulses on a bacteriochlorophyll complex.

- Short impulses mean that energy range that can be coherently induced is very wide. If there is an electron, that gets such beam, it gets excited in many positions at once, relaxes back to starting state radiating ligt in quantum beats. Am I right?
- Did they measure light radiating from reaction centre? Shouldn't it further induce photosynthesis instead of being measurable?